# why does proof that finite intersection of open sets is open not work for infinite sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that an infinite intersection of open sets need not be open as I have seen counter examples, but would like to pin down what part of the proof that a finite intersection of open sets is open doesn't work for infinite sets. On page 34 of Baby Rudin, his proof is that any x in the intersection of open sets F1,F2... has a neighborhood contained in each F. Taking the minimum radius r of all such neighborhoods gives a neighborhood contained in all F, making x interior to the intersection. I believe that the proof doesn't work for infinite sets since there isn't guaranteed to be a minimum of neighborhood radii, even though they are bounded below by 0, since for instance (0,1) has no minimum in the set. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely the case. When you take infinitely many numbers, and even if they are bounded (below), the minimum need not exist.